# How combine two inequalities (complex numbers)?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

This is from a book. I don't understand how the inequalities are combined to one inequality. Are they added/subtracted?

> $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex numbers. We have the inequalities
>   $$\lvert z_2\rvert -\lvert z_1\rvert \leq \lvert z_2-z_1\rvert $$ 
>   $$\lvert z_1\rvert -\lvert z_2\rvert \leq \lvert z_1-z_2\rvert $$
>   Combining these inequalities gives
>   $$\lvert \lvert z_1\rvert -\lvert z_2\rvert \rvert \leq \lvert z_1-z_2\rvert$$

*Attempt*

If I add them:
\begin{align}
\lvert z_2\rvert -\lvert z_1\rvert + \lvert z_1\rvert -\lvert z_2\rvert  &\leq \lvert z_2-z_1\rvert +\lvert z_1-z_2\rvert \\
0&\leq \lvert z_2-z_1\rvert +\lvert z_1-z_2\rvert \\
0&\leq 2\lvert z_1-z_2\rvert
\end{align}
Or if I subtract them:
\begin{align}
\lvert z_2\rvert -\lvert z_1\rvert -(\lvert z_1\rvert -\lvert z_2\rvert)&\leq \lvert z_2-z_1\rvert -( \lvert z_1-z_2\rvert )\\
2\lvert z_2\rvert-2\lvert z_1\rvert &\leq
\lvert z_2-z_1\rvert -\lvert z_1-z_2\rvert\\
2\lvert z_2\rvert-2\lvert z_1\rvert &\leq 0
\end{align}

I'm stuck here!

Answer (score 1):

For $a,b\in\Bbb R$, it holds $\lvert a-b\rvert=\begin{cases} b-a&\text{if }b\ge a\\ a-b&\text{if }a>b\end{cases}$.

In the first case you use one inequality, in the other you use the other one (obviously, $\lvert z_1-z_2\rvert=\lvert z_2-z_1\rvert$).

Comment: Subject says complex numbers.

Comment: @mvg Yeah, but he needs only the real version.

Comment: I should have thought about this for one more second before commenting. Nevertheless, it would be interesting to not rely on this well-known fact, but only on the given properties if possible.

Comment: @MvG How is the definition of absolute value of a real number not a given property when this appears in the problem statement?

Comment: @mathematician The $\lvert z\rvert$ in the problem is the complex modulus $\sqrt{z\overline z}$, which can, in principle, be applied to real numbers as well (aka $\sqrt{x^2}$).

Answer (score 0):

We have $|x|\leq y$ iff $-y\leq x\leq y$ and with
$$\lvert z_2\rvert -\lvert z_1\rvert \leq \lvert z_2-z_1\rvert $$ 
$$\lvert z_1\rvert -\lvert z_2\rvert \leq \lvert z_1-z_2\rvert $$
have
$$-\lvert z_1-z_2\rvert\leq \lvert z_1\rvert -\lvert z_2\rvert \leq \lvert z_1-z_2\rvert $$
iff
$$\Big|\lvert z_1\rvert -\lvert z_2\rvert\Big| \leq \lvert z_1-z_2\rvert $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$|z_1-z_2| = |z_2-z_1|$$

Comment: Wouldn't this be suitable for a Comment?  The OP did a good bit of thinking, and such a brief remark in lieu of a full explanation seems to fall short of the requirements of an Answer.